# Create new Highlight for C pointers

Tags: original-vim

I am trying to highlight only the name of pointer without '->' I tried with syn region but all the pointer and component are highlighted when i use match:

```
syn match PTR1 /\<[0-9A-Za-z_]\{1,\}[-][>]\>/
```

this will produce : **ptr->inPtr->** value = 1

with region it highlight the first -> and doesn't for the rest.

```
syn region ptr1 start=/[0-9A-Za-z_]\{1,\}[-][>]/ skip=/[-][>]/ end=/[0-9A-Za-z_]\{1,\}/
```

this will produce : **ptr->** inptr->value=1

How could I correct it to have only the names highlighted for example : **ptr**->**inPtr**->value = 1

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to add a positive look-ahead for the `->` syntax (you could also use `\ze` or `\zs`, but that tends to cause problems with syntax because the text is consumed; with a look-ahead/behind, that is not the case):

```
:syntax match PTR1 /\<[0-9A-Za-z_]\+\(->\)\@=\>/
```

Note that I've swapped `\{1,\}` for `\+` and used `\(->\)`: the group is necessary with `\@=`, which is a multi that follows an atom; we don't need to character-class `-` or `>` because they do not have special meanings by default.

Simplifying even more, `\w` is equivalent to `[0-9A-Za-z_]` (though you might want to use `\k` instead for `'iskeyword'` characters). I also don't think the word boundaries are necessary.

```
:syntax match PTR1 /\w\+\(->\)\@=/
```

Lastly it's may be a good idea to include `containedin=cBlock` to prevent it from matching in the wrong places and make sure it matches in the right ones, though a few simple tests didn't reveal any issues without it.

Comment: Hi, it is working thank you. However I woul'd like to learn how to fish, where can I get documentations to understand for instance \@=?. Let say I want to change color for **Function_colored**(arg1, ..., argN); here only function name have been colored.

Comment: @lilington start with `:help syntax`, which has nothing to do with `\@=`, and I would recommend peeking at the existing C syntax file, and using one of the various ways to show syntax groups at a given position (useful debugging). The rest is patterns: syntax match uses the same pattern syntax as a search. So `:help pattern`, or more specifically in this case `:help /\@=`.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I thought so, I was hopping for an easier (lazier solution). I will do this than. Thank you again